# Pasar parametro a constructor en UserControl

Tags: c#, xaml

Muy buenas, tengo una aplicación en la cual debería crear tantos objetos del tipo UserControl como valor tenga almacenada en una variable de un ComboBox.
Se crear los objetos pero me gustaría que cada vez que cree uno nuevo, este, incremente el valor de su contador en uno.

El problema es que no se como pasarle al XAML ese numero...
En esta imagen creo que se entendera lo que pido;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen, como necesito 4 objetos los creo automaticamente pero todos parten de la misma clase y tienen el mismo `Header`, es decir, todos se llaman `Configuracion nivel 0`

¿Puedo hacer de alguna manera que cada objeto que cree tenga un numero correlativo? 0,1,2,3,4,5...

Esto del XAML me esta matando...

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

No se la estructura del objeto que creas, pero puedes agregar un metodo que se llame setCount(int) donde al momento de agregar ese control a la vista, le asignas el contador al `TextBlock`.

Por ejemplo digamos que la siguiente clase es la que agregas al control cuando agregas un nivel:

```
public class ConfigNivelControl : UserControl
{
    public ConfigNivelControl(){
      InitializeComponents();
    }

    public void SetCounter(int counter)
    {
       TextBlockContador.Text = counter.ToString();
    }
   // tu codigo...
}
```

Entonces cuando lo inicializes y lo agregues al control, utiliza la instancia y enviale el contador:

```
ConfigNivelControl control = new ConfNivelControl();
// agregas el control al otro control...
//...
//...

// le asignamos el contador:
control.SetContador(variableContador);
```